# SetIcon in Menuitem using Universal Image Loader

Tags: android, android-asynctask, universal-image-loader

I have an actionbar in which I am showing weather. In the `postexecute` method of the `async`, I want to set the image of the weather from a url. By default, the `displayImage` of the `UIL` takes `uri` and `imageWare` in which to display the image.

This is how I am doing it:

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url, (ImageAware) MainActivity.btnWeather.getIcon());
```

Where `btnWeather` is a `menuItem` in the actionbar. I cannot get this to work.. How should I `setIcon` using the UIL..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my project I am using the ImageLoadingListener callback to set the icon resource:

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImage(url, new ImageLoadingListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                            MainActivity.btnWeather.setIcon(new BitmapDrawable(loadedImage));
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {

                        }
                    });
```

Also, you can display custom images when the load starts, fails or is cancelled.